# Python - Changing global variable in a function

Tags: python, global-variables

I have the following code in python:

```
board = 0

def Board1():
    global board
    board = 1

def Board2():
    global board
    board = 2

def Board3(board):
    board = 3
    print board

def ReadBoard():
    print board
```

I think the functions Board1 and Board2 should change the value of the global variable board. But here is what happens: When I call board it returns 0. If I call Board1, the global board value does not change, but if I call ReadBoard, it gives the value Board1 has assigned.
For example (in python console):

```
>>> board  
0  
>>> Board1()  
>>> board  
0  
>>> ReadBoard()  
1  
>>> Board3(board)
3  
>>> board  
0  
>>> board = 4
>>> ReadBoard()
1
```

I could not understand why I cannot change the global variable globally and why am I reading the changed variable in the ReadBoard function.

Comment: First please fix your indentation in your functions

Comment: -1 for not mentioning at all that you did `from somemoduleididntmention import *`, which you should never do and which is also your entire problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a Python module that defines `board`. In your console you have another, distinct object that you name `board`. When you output `board` from your console you get that object. When your module that contains your functions prints `board`, it prints the object defined in that module.

So the fundamental problem is that you have two things that you call `board`.

I expect that you imported the module like this:

```
from MyModule import *
```

Having done that you've no way to distinguish between the two `board` objects. So instead use:

```
import MyModule
```

Then you can use `MyModule.board` to refer to the global `board` defined in the module.

Answer (score 1):

After you import the global variable `board` into your Python console once, it doesn't change. Try putting that code into your file (as print statements) rather than executing it in the console and it should work.